# Amazon Kinesis KPL SerializationException

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I get

```
2016-03-21 10:17:19.915081] [0x00007f539b023740] [error] [retrier.cc:59] PutRecords failed: {"__type":"SerializationException"}
```

With the following Java stacktrace:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.onPutRecordResult(KinesisProducer.java:188)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.access$000(KinesisProducer.java:127)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler$1.run(KinesisProducer.java:134)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In our case the cause was that the `PartitionKey` contained quote characters (`"`). This is not forbidden by the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html#API_PutRecord_RequestSyntax), but rather probably a "string injection" problem in the c++ code in the KPL. So in the call `kp.addUserRecord(streamName, partitionKey, data);`, make sure that `partitionKey` doesn't contain any quote characters.

Comment: AFAIK, partition key also cannot contain "-" (dash) characters.